# Организация хранения библиотек проекта

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Добрый день.
Работаю с библиотекой libbotan (https://github.com/randombit/botan).
Данная библиотека не совсем windows-френдли. Чтобы использовать её в данный момент для моего приложения, приходится хранить 2 набора собранных либ для линковки (х86 и х64), кроме того для дебаг версии либы идут с постфиксом 'd'. Получается набор из 4-х версий либы.
На данный момент подключение реализовано через .h файл следующего вида

```
// link_botan.h
#ifdef WIN32
  #ifdef _DEBUG
    #pragma comment (lib, "botand32d.lib")
  #else
    #pragma comment (lib, "botand32.lib")
  #endif
#else
  #ifdef _DEBUG
    #pragma comment (lib, "botand64d.lib")
  #else
    #pragma comment (lib, "botand64.lib")
  #endif
#endif
```

Как наиболее правильно реализовать линковку с подобными либами для более простого использования? (Кроме этого способа еще можно городить условия в .vcxproj или вместо постфиксов использовать папки)

Comment: обычно, в таких случаях просто в настроках проекта добавляют для каждого варианта и никто не жалуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть альтеративный способ

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DPREF "d"
#else
#define DPREF ""
#endif

#ifdef WIN32
#define PLAT "32"
#else
#define PLAT "64"
#endif

// link_botan.h
#pragma comment (lib, "botand" PLAT DPREF ".lib")
```

да, для 64 битный лучше проверять на `_WIN64`

Проще ли этот способ - я не знаю. Но если нужно подключать несколько библиотек, то определение DPREF/PLAT можно вынести в отдельный файл (ну и конечно переименовать).

Comment: #ifdef WIN32 определяется даже когда стоит платформа x64

Comment: ага, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

Comment: за проверку на _WIN64 спасибо.